# Why is the MediaStream object in this case empty?

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I'm connecting my browser and server(nodejs) with a RTCpeerconnection using `node-webrtc`. The connection happens successfully as far as chrome://webrtc-internals indicates. Further, my browser receives a MediaStream object that, although does not contain a live video because its from the server, is a solid object. However, the important part, which is the server receiving a MediaStream object, is not working.

When I try to log the stream received by the server via ontrack, it displays `MediaStream {}` and the said object is empty. Why is that and how can I get the object to be received properly?

I don't think my code is nec but I'll post if you think its a specific issue and not a general one.

Comment: Check `event.track` and `event.streams[0].getTracks().length`.

Comment: event.track is `MediaStreamTrack {}` and the length is 1. The length looks good right?

Comment: The length is the same on the browser as well

Comment: How are you logging the object? Are you asking why the object appears empty or why video is not flowing? There's not enough info here to know the latter. I have no experience with node-webrtc so I probably won't be able to help if this is specific to that. You should be able to see if media is flowing in chrome://webrtc-internals, or by using `getStats`. Also check `track.muted`.

Comment: Console.log(event.streams[0]). I checked if the issue was here as well but the logging works fine for the offer that is sent through. Could there be issues when logging objects that are generated in a event callback function on the server side?

Comment: The issue was unrelated to webrtc but I was able to track it down because of your help. Thank you

Comment: @Username WHAT WAS THE ISUE>!

Comment: I cannot recall the exact issue but the problem was that node-webrtc did not support creating and then sending media stream objects. I was unable to resolve it so I had to create the MediaStream in the browser first. @bluejayke

Comment: @Username ok thans for the input